# Object #<Object> has no method 'connect'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

i get this error on console....
my html code is simple
and socket server starts successfully
following is my code:

```
<doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket =io.connect('ws://localhost:3000');

  socket.on('news', function (data) 
{
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
Welcome to Sockets.IO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var socket = new io.Socket('localhost',{
    port: 8080
});
socket.connect();
```

This may work, just change the values according to yours one.

You should check this link, it will help you out.
http://davidwalsh.name/websocket